# How do I get an IF statement to read a multilined textbox?

Tags: xml, vb.net, if-statement

I have a multiline textbox and its text contains this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<version>6</version>
```

and I'm trying to do a if command like this

```
    If TextBox3.Text = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" + "<version>6</version>" Then
        msg = "No new updates"
    ElseIf "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" + "<version>7</version>" Then
        msg = "New update available"
    End If
```

but I cannot seem to get the textbox to read the 2 lines of code and it just keeps skipping it, how could I get the IF command to read both lines and and say No new updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    If TextBox3.Text.Contains("<version>6</version>") Then
        msg = "No new updates"
    ElseIf TextBox3.Text.Contains("<version>7</version>") Then
        msg = "New update available"
    End If
```

Will solve your specific problem, though I'm sure if you explained what you want to achieve, there would be a better way.